# Filtering out faint sobel filter lines?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, sobel

I'm using skimage to creator a sobel filter image similar to this...
[image]

I was wondering is there a way to sharpen this sobel filter image? To say, remove the white lines that are more faint like for example the faint lines behind the air balloons?

I used Skimage to do this, but I can get access to other things like OpenCV.

My code specifically is...

```
from skimage.filters import sobel
elevation_map = sobel(img)
plt.imshow(elevation_map, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

Comment: Can you give us the original image?

Comment: Sadly I can't, but also just in general how could I sharpen a photo like that up since it won't just be used for one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late but the simplest way to remove faint pixels is to apply a threshold to the image.

It can be done like this (with a threshold of 50 for instance) `elevation_map[elevation_map < 50] = 0`
You can adjust the threshold to get more of less dark gray pixels set to 0.

Comment: Ah yes that's actually what we ended up figuring out. Thank you though, forgot about this question!